# Reimplement resize event

Tags: c++, qt

My widget is frameless because of the sleek looks and so I need to reimplement the resize behaviour.

If I drag the bottom right corner it already works with this code:

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    resize(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());
}
```

But what about all the other corners? For example the bottom left corner.
As one expects, it should behave as if the top right corner of the widget would be fixed.
But in the resize function, the upper left corner is fixed, because there is the `event.pos()==0`.
My idea was to resize the window and then move it, so that it looks as if it would not move, but only change size around the upper left corner. As this leads to flickering and even not the perfect result, is there a better way?

EDIT: Solution:

a) You can define in `mousePressEvent`:

```
offset = event->pos();
initialFixedCornerPosX = this->width()+this->pos().x();
initialFixedCornerPosY = this->pos().y();
```

and in `mouseMoveEvent`

```
int x = event->globalX();
int y = event->globalY();
int x_w = offset.x();
int y_w = offset.y();
setGeometry(x-x_w,initialFixedCornerPosY,initialFixedCornerPosX-x+x_w,y-initialFixedCornerPosY);
```

or

b) in `mouseMoveEvent`

```
QRect rect = geometry();
rect.setBottomLeft(event->globalPos());
setGeometry(rect);
```

Comment: Try `setGeometry`, which can move and resize in the very same moment

Comment: Of course you need to figure out more numbers for this call. But I guess it should be possible when you use the old `geometry()` for this.

Comment: Yes of course. Right now I have the idea to save the upper right corner's position on `mousePressEvent`, that's when the user clicks on the bottom left corner.

Comment: You can also use the `QRect` returned by `geometry()`, then (depending on which corner is pressed) use the setters for the individual corners of the rectangle to modify it (example: [`rect.setBottomLeft(event->pos())`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qrect.html#setBottomLeft) and then use this rect for `setGeometry`

Comment: Very neat trick. I have made an edit to my post, you can answer this and I accept it, thank you :)

The only drawback vs. the resize on the standard bottom right corner is (both a) and b)), that the right side of the widget slides a bit while resizing (in the end has the correct position). But as I see, the same behaviour with the Windows7 sticky notes.

Comment: You should post your own solution as an answer to your own question, not as an edit. It is perfectly fine to have asker give one or more answers to her/his own question. Answers never belong within a question. After you address this issue, please flag this comment as obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To both resize *and* move the window in one step without flickering, you should use [`QWidget::setGeometry(QRect)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) by providing a modified rectangle previously fetched using the corresponding getter function [`QWidget::geometry()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop).

```
QRect rect = geometry();
// (then modify...)
setGeometry(rect);
```

To modify a corner of a `QRect`, you could either modify each edge or the corners directly. Depending on the rest of your logic, one makes more sense than the other. I'd prefer the second of the following two options:

**Example using corners:**

If you detect that the user drags the bottom left corner, use

```
rect.setBottomLeft(event->pos());
```

However, you of course need to consider edges too, and if you consider corners as separate cases this results in eight cases to be considered in the mouse event.

**Example using only edges:**

If you detect that the mouse is on the left edge (it might be as well on the top or bottom corner, which are only special cases, so for now we ignore that):

```
rect.setLeft(event->pos().x());
```

and if you detect it is on the bottom edge, then

```
rect.setBottom(event->pos().y());
```

so if both cases are true, this effectively moves the corner of the rect. So you only need to consider four cases to drag all edges and corners of your window! This assumes that you have a single widget which handles the resize (i.e. your top level widget, which has a margin on the layout to have the children not touch the window edge), and *do not* add a widget for each corner / edge.